# Pandas read_excel: Suppress MultiIndex when missing column 2 header

Tags: python, excel, pandas

We have a data system that creates tables of data as Excel files. I'm trying to import this Excel file into a pandas dataframe.

In the Excel, Row 1 is some metadata I don't want, while row 2 is the column header.  By default, Pandas correctly uses column 1 as the index (a lot number), but the second column is a production date, but it for what ever reason does not have a header in row 2.

So pandas seems to be creating a multi-index by default, is there a way to suppress this function?  It seems to be doing this because there is no column header in row 2 column 2 (cell B2).  If I manually edit the Excel to add a label, it imports as I want.

```
import pandas as pd
xlsx01 = pd.ExcelFile("C:/Users/maherp/Desktop/JunkFiles/Book1.xlsx")

df_01 = pd.read_excel(xlsx01, header=1)
```

I get an error that I cannot decipher when I try:

```
df_01 = pd.read_excel(xlsx01, header=1, index_col=0)
```

[image: spreadsheet snipit]

Comment: Have you tried using the "names" argument to read_excel? Something like:
`pd.read_excel(xlsx01, header=1, names=['lot_number', 'date', 'job_type', 'data1', 'data2'])`

Comment: @mgrollins I plan on processing numerous excel spreadsheets and each will have different column headers.  Also the spreadsheets themselves have 30+ columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Peej1226, here is final solution which worked.

```
df_01 = pd.read_excel(xlsx01, sheet_name='Discrete', skiprows=1, header=0,index_col=0)
```

Comment: The error code says 
`ParserError: Expected 32 fields in line 3, saw 33`
I have 33 total columns (screen shot is only the first 5).  So minus the index column, I have 32 columns of data.  Is it counting the index again?

Comment: What's really frustrating is if I put anything in cell B2, there is no error.  I tested this by modifying the file with OpenPyxl and it works.
But the files I'm reading from are readonly.

Comment: I don't think it's counting the index again as we are already defining the `index _col=0` . Try using `df_01 = pd.read_excel(xlsx01,skiprows=2, header=None, index_col=0)` and see if it works.

Comment: That removed the header, but I monkeyed around and this seems to work.  

`df_01 = pd.read_excel(xlsx01, sheet_name='Discrete', skiprows=1, header=0,index_col=0)`

Comment: if you update your post I will vote for it as correct.